# Raspberry Pi playing music via Floppy Drive components?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've been interested for months in making something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3jOitAgcCI), but I have never figured out how it's done.

- How is he controlling the Floppy drive via the Pi?
- Does anyone know of any software which can help me in this project, to make the Pi parse midi files which will send them over to the Floppy to be outputted?

Answer (score 4):

The guy who did it provided this:

http://pccode.pl/floppi-i-gra-muzyka-na-stacjach-dyskietek-i-raspberry-pi/

You may need to translate it from Polish first (link may not work):

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://pccode.pl/floppi-i-gra-muzyka-na-stacjach-dyskietek-i-raspberry-pi/&sandbox=0&usg=ALkJrhhZmLsEctb80ehFXL1F3Pa8-ozPlg

A bigger problem may be tuning the floppy disk drives first. The software used may be proprietary anyway.

There is also an article here: http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sandbox=0&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://pclab.pl/news51884.html&usg=ALkJrhjgKiKgq4y3OzwOTNJK4wmQa69u7Q

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial in actual English?

Comment: The 'http://pccode.pl/....' was in the comment below the YouTube video. As it was in Polish, I used Google Translate, which is annoying, but works. But you can find in the article that he used proprietary software to operate the floppy disk heads at different frequencies, thus creating the noise.